# Friedberg Linear Algebra Theorem 1.5

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-explanation

I was reading Friedberg Linear Algebra after Axler and I noticed that Friedberg says the span of any subset S but Axler says the span of a LIST of vectors $v_1,..,v_n$.

The question is: Is Friedberg making an implicit assumption in the proof that S is finite since he enumerates the elements of S ?

[image: Friedberg Linear Algebra Question]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no assumption that $S$ is finite. In fact they are *not* enumerating elements of $S$ anywhere in the proof. By *definition*, an element in the span of $S$ is a *finite* linear combination of elements of $S$ (even though $S$ might be infinite). The reason for this is that in general there is no way to make sense out of an infinite sum of vectors (unless our vector space is equipped with extra structure, see e.g. Banach spaces and Schauder bases).

Comment: Hello Alex. The definition Friedberg states is: "Let S be a nonempty subset of a vector space V. The span of S, denoted span(S), is the set consisting of allL the linear combinations of the VECTORS in S." As you can see he said the VECTORS in S, NOT a "finite number of vectors in S".

Comment: @Nameless I think I have an older edition, but look at their definition of a linear combination (beginning of section 1.4 for me): "a vector $x \in V$ is said to be a *linear combination* of elements of $S$ is there exists a *finite* number of elements..."

Comment: You are right. Thanks a million for your guidance. Have a great day.

Comment: @Nameless You're very welcome! Have a great day too.